# In the movie In Bruges, which is the clock tower

Tags: in-bruges

In the mvoie in bruges they visit a specific tower a few times. Where is that clock tower in real life? I just visited the clock tower in the city Bruges and it looks nothing like the movie version. Did they actually film in the interior of The Belfort? If so did they make any changes for better scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's The Belfort that's seen in the movie.

Also,
According to IMDB, "the scene in which Ray and Ken visit the Basilica of the Holy Blood is in fact filmed in the Jerusalem Church, Bruges" [IMDB filming](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780536/trivia?item=tr0757468)

If one inputs either location in Google Earth "Search" one can compare the two locations from street level.  They aren't that far from each other.

Comment: I am talking about the clock tower from which Ken jumped off. Tjat is the basilica?

Comment: I 'fixed' my answer as you were typing your comment. lol.

Comment: But I just came from belfort. It's not the same as in the movie. The stairs and the bell etc

Comment: I've not been within Belfort.  You do mention "in the real tower" but I would edit the question to state, "interior", as in "Was the interior of The Belfort used for filming....?"  This would emphasize what you're question is really about.

Comment: Edited my question